# Perl + recursive subroutine + accessing variable defined outside of subroutine

Tags: perl, recursion

I am pulling bitbucket repo list using Perl. The response from bitbucket will contain only 10 repositories and a marker for the next page where there will be another 10 repos and so on ... (they call it paging response)

So, I wrote a recursive subroutine which calls itself if the next page marker is present. This will continue until it reaches the last page.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;

my @array;

recursive("my_bitbucket_url");
foreach ( @array ) { print $_."\n"; }

sub recursive
{
    my $url    = $_[0];

    ### here goes my LWP::UserAgent code which connects to bitbucket and pulls back the response in a JSON as $response->decoded_content 
    ### hence, removing this code for brevity

    my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    #print Dumper ($hash);

    foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
    {
        push @array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
    }

    if ( defined $hash->{next})
    {
        print "Next page Exists \n";
        print "Recursing with $hash->{next} \n";
        recursive( $hash->{next} );
    }
    else
    {
        print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n"
    }
}
```

Now, my code works fine and it lists all the repos.

**Question:**
I am not sure about the way I have used the variable **`my @array;`** above. I have defined it outside the subroutine, However, I am accessing it directly from the subroutine. Somehow, I feel this is not right.

So, how to append to an array using a recursive subroutine in such cases. Does my code obey Perl ethics or is it something really absurd (yet correct because it works) ?

**UPDATE**

After following suggestions from @ikegami, @Sobrique and @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, I have come with below code which uses `while` loop and avoids recusrsion.

Here is my thought process:

1. Define an array `@array`.
2. Call the subroutine `call_url` with initial bitbucket URL and save the response in `$hash`
3. Check the `$hash` for the *next* page marker

   - If *next* page marker exists, then push the elements to `@array` and call `call_url` with the new marker. This will be done with the `while` loop.
   - If the *next* page marker does **NOT** exists, then push the elements to `@array`. Period.
4. Print `@array` content.

And here is my code:

```
my @array;
my $hash = call_url("my_bitbucket_url ");

if (defined $hash->{next})
{
    while (defined $hash->{next})
    {
        foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
        {
            push @array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
        }
        $hash = call_url($hash->{next});
    }
}

foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
{
    push @array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
}

foreach (@array) { print $_."\n"; }

sub call_url
{
    ### here goes my LWP::UserAgent code which connects to bitbucket and pulls back the response in a JSON as $response->decoded_content 
    ### hence, removing this code for brevity    

    my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    #print Dumper ($hash);

    return $hash;
}
```

Would definitely like to hear whether this looks OK or is there still a room for improvement.

Comment: `if defined` followed by `while defined` is redundant - if it's the same condition, the `while` will bypass if the condition is untrue.

Comment: Ugh.  "hash" and "array" are terrible names for variables.  How about "repo" or, even better, "current_repo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable defined outside any closures is available to the whole program. It works fine, there's nothing to worry about. Some might call it 'bad style' in certain cases (mostly around program length and action at distance) but that's not a hard constraint.

I'm not sure I necessarily see the advantage of recursion here though - your problem doesn't *seem* to warrant it. That's not a problem per-se, but it can be a little confusing for future maintenance programmers ;).

I'd be thinking something along the lines of (non recursive):

```
my $url = "my_bitbucket_url";

while ( defined $url ) {
    ##LWP Stuff;

    my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;

    foreach my $element ( @{ $hash->{values} } ) {
        print join( "\n", @{ $element->{links}->{self}->{href} } ), "\n";
    }

    $url = $hash->{next}; #undef if it doesn't exist, so loop breaks. 
}
```

Comment: Each response will list only 10 repos and a marker for "next" 10 repos. Hence, I need to run the same procedure multiple times unlit I reach the "last" page. As I had to figure out the "marker" in each response and make the exact same LWP call, I made it recursive. Thanks.

Comment: I'd consider recursive subs for things like tree traversals - e.g. following every link from a web page. Fetching pages until you stop getting "next" feels more like a `while` loop to me. But as said - it's not a massive problem if you want to do it that way.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, Doing something until a condition is met is exactly what a while loop does. Sobrique is right; recursion should not be used here.

Comment: @ikegami: I don't see a reason to not use recursion for this work. But it has to be done right. Imagine there are languages without while and other loops at all and you can do everything as well. Lack of tail call optimization is perl's problem.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, What are you talking about? There are numerous reasons not to use recursion here. It's a big perfomance sink, and it needlessly complex code. In turn, this negatively affects maintainability, readability, reliability, etc. There's not a single good reason to use it, so I reiterate: **Recursion should absolutely not be used here.** (What other languages can or can't do has no effect on any of that. No idea why you brought that up.)

Comment: @ikegami: Are you sure about performance sink? Have you compared mine tricky_tail_recursion with the while loop? I strongly doubt it.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, Yeah, `goto &` actually makes things *slower* than a normal call, and that's slower than no call at all. On top of that, sub calls are one of the slower Perl ops.

Answer (score 3):

Using global variables to return values demonstrates [high coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29), something to be avoided.

You're asking if the following is acceptable:

```
my $sum;
sum(4, 5);
print("$sum\n");
sub sum {
   my ($x, $y) = @_;
   $sum = $x + $y;
}
```

The fact that the sub is recursive is completely irrelevant; it just makes your example larger.

---

Problem fixed:

```
sub recursive
{
    my $url = $_[0];

    my @array;

    my $hash = ...;

    foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
    {
        push @array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
    }

    if ( defined $hash->{next})
    {
        print "Next page Exists \n";
        print "Recursing with $hash->{next} \n";
        push @array, recursive( $hash->{next} );
    }
    else
    {
        print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n"
    }

    return @array;
}

{
    my @array = recursive("my_bitbucket_url");
    foreach ( @array ) { print $_."\n"; }
}
```

---

Recursion removed:

```
sub recursive
{
    my $url = $_[0];

    my @array;
    while (defined($url)) {    
        my $hash = ...;

        foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
        {
            push @array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
        }

        $url = $hash->{next};

        if ( defined $url)
        {
            print "Next page Exists \n";
            print "Recursing with $url\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n"
        }
    }

    return @array;
}

{
    my @array = recursive("my_bitbucket_url");
    foreach ( @array ) { print $_."\n"; }
}
```

---

Clean up of the latest code you posted:

```
my $url = "my_bitbucket_url";

my @array;
while ($url) {
    my $hash = call_url($url);

    for my $value ( @{ $hash->{values} } ) {
       push @array, $value->{links}{self}{href};
    }

    $url = $hash->{next};
}

print("$_\n") for @array;
```

Comment: Agree on your last statement. Thanks for providing a dummy code which explains my question. So, per your response, this works however it should be avoided. So then, How to go about appending the values from each call to the subroutine to an array. Not sure if my question is little confusing, however, as you have pointed out, this code should be avoided. So, is there a better approach?

Comment: Same thing you'd do for `sum`: Move the var into the sub and use `return` to return its contents

Comment: I think that might be worth asking as a separate question if you want a fuller answer.

Comment: Might need to undef `$url` in that `else` block.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, The `if (defined $hash->{next})` is unnecessary, and I'd try to remove that duplicated foreach. But there's a sister site for code reviews.

Comment: @Sobrique, Indeed. Fixed.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, Added simple version of your latest code.

Comment: @ikegami, as always, many thanks for your elaborative answer. Wish I could +1 many time. I would accept @Sobrique's answer as he got me thinking into `while` approach instead of recursive sub. Nonetheless, your responses always trigger a lot of self-learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using a global variable is bad habit even it is lexical scoped variable.

Each recursive code can be rewritten into its imperative loop version and vice versa. It is because all of this is implemented on CPU which doesn't know anything about recursion at all. Thre are only jumps. All calls and returns are just jumps with some stack manipulation so you can rewrite your recursion algorithm into loop. If it is not obvious and simple as in this case you can even emulate stack and behaviour as it is done in your favourite language interpreter or compiler. In this case it's very simple:

```
my @array = with_loop("my_bitbucket_url");
foreach ( @array ) { print $_."\n"; }

sub with_loop
{
    my $url    = $_[0];
    my @array;
    while(1) 
    {

    ### here goes my LWP::UserAgent code which connects to bitbucket and 
    ### pulls back the response in a JSON as $response->decoded_content 
    ### hence, removing this code for brevity

        my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
        #print Dumper ($hash);

        foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
        {
            push @array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
        }

        unless ( defined $hash->{next})
        {
            print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n";
            last
        };

        print "Next page Exists \n";
        print "Recursing with $hash->{next} \n";
        $url = $hash->{next};
    };
    return @array;
}
```

But when you would like to stick with recursion you can but it is a little bit more tricky. First of all, there is not tail call optimization so you don't have to try write tail call code as your original version does. So you can do this:

```
my @array = recursion("my_bitbucket_url");
foreach ( @array ) { print $_."\n"; }

sub recursion
{
    my $url    = $_[0];

    ### here goes my LWP::UserAgent code which connects to bitbucket and 
    ### pulls back the response in a JSON as $response->decoded_content 
    ### hence, removing this code for brevity

    my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    #print Dumper ($hash);

    # this map version is same as foreach with push but more perlish
    my @array = map $_->{links}->{self}->{href}, @{$hash->{values}};

    if (defined $hash->{next})
    {
        print "Next page Exists \n";
        print "Recursing with $hash->{next} \n";
        push @array, recursive( $hash->{next} );
    }
    else
    {
        print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n"
    }
    return @array;
}
```

But this version is not very efficient so there is way how to write tail call recursive version in perl which is a little bit tricky.

```
my @array = tail_recursive("my_bitbucket_url");
foreach ( @array ) { print $_."\n"; }

sub tail_recursive
{
    my $url    = $_[0];
    my @array;
    return tail_recursive_inner($url, \@array); 
    # url is mutable parameter
}

sub tail_recursive_inner
{
    my $url = $_[0];
    my $array = $_[1]; 
    # $array is reference to accumulator @array 
    # from tail_recursive function

   ### here goes my LWP::UserAgent code which connects to bitbucket and 
   ### pulls back the response in a JSON as $response->decoded_content 
   ### hence, removing this code for brevity

    my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    #print Dumper ($hash);

    foreach my $a ( @{$hash->{values}} )
    {
        push @$array, $a->{links}->{self}->{href};
    }

    if (defined $hash->{next})
    {
        print "Next page Exists \n";
        print "Recursing with $hash->{next} \n";

        # first parameter is mutable so its OK to assign
        $_[0] = $hash->{next};
        goto &tail_recursive_inner;
    }
    else
    {
        print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n"
    }
    return @$array;
}
```

And if you are interested in some real perl trickery

```
print $_."\n" for tricky_tail_recursion("my_bitbucket_url");

sub tricky_tail_recursion {
    my $url = shift;

   ### here goes my LWP::UserAgent code which connects to bitbucket and 
   ### pulls back the response in a JSON as $response->decoded_content 
   ### hence, removing this code for brevity

    my $hash = decode_json $response->decoded_content;
    #print Dumper ($hash);

    push @_, $_->{links}->{self}->{href} for @{$hash->{values}}; 

    if (defined $hash->{next}) {
        print "Next page Exists \n";
        print "Recursing with $hash->{next} \n";
        unshift @_, $hash->{next};
        goto &tricky_tail_recursion;
    } else {
        print "Last page reached. No more recursion \n"
    };
    return @_;
}
```

---

See also: [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://www.metacpan.org/LWP::UserAgent) docs.

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah, I can do 3.7 million `goto &code;` calls per second which is 270ns vs 32ns while loops. It really bothers me in the loop with  `LWP` usage. Sorry, you made me laugh. Yep, it is less readable than the while loop in this particular case, but it is mostly Perl problem. There is not any reason why it should be slow at first, and complicated at second.

Comment: You're the one who brought up efficiency. Efficiency is not the reason I gave for why your solution is bad. What about the extra complexity you added to added to make your code slower? That affects readability, maintainability, etc, etc. You're providing bad advice.

Comment: I think a discussion about recursion might be interesting, but perhaps not in the comments :). I'm sure there's a question that could be posed....

Comment: @ikegami: "It's a big perfomance sink." Yep, it was me who brought up efficiency :-)

Comment: @ikegami: There is not anything wrong with recursion. There is a lot of wrong with recursion in Perl. Recursion is simpler, less complex and easyer to maintain that imperative loops like `while`. All problems what you are talking are Perl problems, not recursion at all.

Comment: @ikegami: "**Recursion should absolutely not be used here.**" Original code was written with recursion. Maybe because it was the natural way to thing about it for the original author of the code. So rewriting to imperative while loop is **forcing** the other unnatural way to thing about the problem. So show me way how to writte it better in recursion but without growing stack in Perl. It should not be problem for you when you insist "You're providing bad advice."

Comment: So you could not write better recursive version and you criticise mine one. Nice, what else you got? I'm glad we both agree Perl is bad language to express natural way to thing about problems.

Comment: It is disputable if it is the better solution to change the algorithm to nonrecursive when question is about recursive one.

Comment: I did solve scoping as well as you. Or do solve your solution scoping better than mine? It was started with "**Recursion should absolutely not be used here.**" Do you remember? Or help me to recall what is problem there.

Comment: I didn't wrote you wrote mine solution didn't work. Straw man.

Comment: "Or do solve your solution scoping better than mine?" -- Implies it in any part what so ever **it didn't work**?

Comment: And your solution introduces other problems as well. For example, you force imperative loop where it is natural to thing about it recursively. It is bad for maintainability and readability of code.

Comment: It was definitely natural way for the original question. The original code was: Read Document, If there is next do it again. It is the natural way to thing about it for me, it is the natural way for the author of the original question and it is even natural way for children to thing in this way. It is the lack of abilities of Perl you can't write the problem in natural way.

Comment: @ikegami: So you are again referring to crap Perl support for even basic recursive functions. Thanks.

Comment: The code is complex because Perl has wrong argument handling and lack of tail call elimination. It is very simple in any sane programming language. It is usually as simple as `foo(Url) -> foo(Url, []). foo(Url, Acc) -> Data = call_url(URL), NewAcc = add_refs(Data, Acc), case get_next(Data) of undefined -> NewAcc; NextUrl -> foo(NextUrl, NewAcc)  end.`

Comment: The code is complex because of optimizations you chose to add. There are less complex solutions available.

Comment: Have you seen example code in Erlang? What is complex about it? Why original question contain recursive code? You are just choosing to be blind  and it is your choose. Keep going blind.

Comment: I said **Your solution is needlessly complex**. Erlang has nothing to do with it your code being complex. By pointing out it's simpler in other language, you are proving that your code is complex.

Comment: **Perl lack support for writing clean and natural recursive code!** That's the point. You just can't accept this simple true. So keep living in your imaginary world.